# merge two columns and sorting in SQL CE

Tags: sql, database, merge

I have these two columns to be merged into Column3 and sorted like the way below (first element from column1 then second element from column2 and so on) by using SQLCE in C#.

```
 Column1   Column2
 -------   -------
  pear     banana
  apple    pineapple
   .         .
   .         .
   .         .

     Column3
     -------
       pear
       banana
       apple
       pineapple
       .
       .
       .
```

Comment: [Column1] + CHAR(13) + [Column2] ?

Comment: What do you mean by CHAR(13)?

Comment: CHAR(13) is a newline character, your output shows pear (then a newline) then banana.....

Comment: my output should look like Column3

Comment: Makes no sense to me....you want one huge value (one row) or each item is a row in column 3 ?

Comment: each item is a row in column3

Comment: Can you please re word your question, is Column1 and Column2 seperate tables? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: How are your columns currently sorted?

Comment: Column1 and Column2 are seperate columns in a table. i need to merge them by first element from column1 then second element from column2 and so on to compose column3.

Comment: If they are unsorted then your question seems a bit pointless. You just want some random value from Column1 followed by a random value from Column2?

Comment: -1 This question does not make any sense sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select fields1, fields2, fields1+ CHAR(13) +fields2 as ResultName From emp

The result that u want will be :

```
pear
banana

apple 
pineapple

....
....
```

Comment: any way to avoid the newline in the result would be appreciated.

Comment: -1 for taking my comment and spitting it into code :)...If you dont want the newline eliminate `CHAR(13)` - `SELECT field1 + field2...`

Comment: :) is not like yours, u can try it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you something close to what you seem to be looking for:

```
SELECT
    Column1 AS Column3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1) AS row_number,
    1 AS second_sort
FROM
    My_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Column2 AS Column3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column2) AS row_number,
    2 AS second_sort
FROM
    My_Table
ORDER BY
    row_number,
    second_sort
```

You can put that into a subquery or as a CTE if you want to exclude the extra ordering columns from your results.

Comment: OVER is not supported in SQLCE unfortunately.

Comment: The `ROW_NUMBER()` was there because you don't seem to have any actual ordering of the results, so it was basically a contrived ordering. Without any actual ordering I doubt that this can be done in a set-based way and you're stuck with cursors or handling it on the front end.